# How to accumulate multiple observables and emit latest after some time (debounce)

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am trying to implement the following idea

I have some object that emits events regulary, but I am interested only in most recent ones. Here is how it looks like in code

```
private void someEvent() {
    List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
    // do something
    addEventObservable(generateEventObservable(companyIds));
}

private Observable<SomeValue> generateEventObservable(List<Object> object) {
   // generate observable in this case fetch some data from network
}

private void addEventObservable(Observable<SomeValue> observ) { 
   // Accumulate all incoming observables, but emit the most recent one
   // Get result ad invoke callback
}
```

Consider that `someEvent` is the event of typing text and on every typed charcter I am generating an observable and pass it `addEventObservable`. In this method I need somehow accumulate all received observables and only after some period of time run the most recent one.

I can achieve this using timer, or post delayed by just adding into some Queue object. But maybe there is any way to implement this using RxJAva elegantelly ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the RxBinding library ('com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:1.0.1') to turn views into streams.

first, convert the `EditText` into an `Observable` stream. this will emit an event for changes in text, much like a `TextWatcher`:

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(companyIdsEditText)
```

then, as your title suggests, you can use the `debounce` operator to wait for a pause in user input. here i'll apply it to wait for a 500ms pause in user input:

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(companyIdsEditText)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

you could further apply some optional filtering, for example if there's a minimum length for a company ID of five characters:

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(companyIdsEditText)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(new Func1<CharSequence,Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    return charSequence != null && charSequence.toString().length() >= 5;
                }
            })
```

now you're ready to make your network call based on your user input. to do so we'll `flatMap()` the user input in order to create another `Observable` for the result type:

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(companyIdsEditText)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(new Func1<CharSequence,Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    return charSequence != null && charSequence.toString().length() >= 5;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<CharSequence,Observable<SomeDataType>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<SomeDataType> call(CharSequence s) {
                    // make network call and return your result here...
                    // returning null here as a substitute for actual data...
                    return null;
                }
            })
```

and finally, nothing happens unless we subscribe to our `Observable` instance:

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(companyIdsEditText)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(new Func1<CharSequence,Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    return charSequence != null && charSequence.toString().length() >= 5;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<CharSequence,Observable<SomeDataType>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<SomeDataType> call(CharSequence s) {
                    // make network call and return your result here...
                    // returning null here as a substitute for actual data...
                    return null;
                }
            })
    .subscribe(
            // onNext handler...
            // onError handler...
            // onComplete handler...
    );
```

i hope that helps!